# Inner product space - Algebras over fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Since a K-Algebra is just a vector space with field K together with a bilinear product, is it true that all inner product spaces are K-Algebras?

Comment: an inner product is a function $A \times A \to \mathbb{C}$ while the multiplication of an algebra is $A \times A \to A$.

Comment: So.. an inner product maps elements of a vector space to elements of the "underlying field" of the vector space, whereas the multiplication of elements in an Algebra maps elements of a vector space to the vector space itself?

Comment: Yes. One more difference: An inner product is usually only defined if the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: A concrete example: $K[X]$ (polynomials over $K$) form a $K$-algebra  under the usual polynomial product (this is a countably-infinite dimensional vector space), but the polynomial product is not an inner product. Another example: the vector space $\text{Hom}_K(V,V)$ of all $K$-linear endomorphisms of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ (often represented by matrices) is a $K$-algebra under point-wise addition and scalar multiplication, and composition of functions, this is different than the usual inner-product of that space given by $\langle A,B\rangle = \text{tr}(B^TA)$